# Is the electric field due to moving charge conservative?

Tags: electromagnetism

I know the electric field due to stationary charge is conservative.

$\int{\vec{E}}\bullet d\vec{l}=0$

It can be derived by coulomb's law and stoke's theorem.

But i'm wondering in the case of electric field due to moving charge.Or is this too difficult thing?

Comment: A moving charge leads to a time-varying magnetic field, so by Faraday's law the E-field is not conservative.

Comment: @Puk that comment should be an answer

Answer (score 2):

If the charge moves through free space, then at any position in space, the Ampere-Maxell law says
$$\nabla \times {\bf B} = \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial {\bf E}}{\partial t}$$

As the charge moves, the electric field at any point in space will be changing with time and so there will also be a curling B-field that is also time-dependent.

Then, since Faraday's law says
$$\nabla \times {\bf E} = - \frac{\partial {\bf B}}{\partial t}\ , $$
a time-dependent B-field means that the electric field cannot be conservative, since its curl is not zero.

Edit: If you are talking about a group of moving charges then obviously you have to consider the total E-field from them all. If you change the charge distribution then there will be a changing E-field and all the above applies.

A *steady* current is not associated with a change in charge distribution or a changing E-field.

Comment: Then, electric field by constant current is also non conservative?

Comment: @KHJ Good point, I was writing on the basis of A moving charge. The situation of a "constant current" is that there is no $\partial E/\partial t$ (and in fact no E-field at all) just a current density. But then how do you make a constant current - you have to *start* moving some charges and then you do have a $\partial E/\partial t$.

Comment: There can be constant current with and with or without a change in charge density. E.g a loop of current has no change in charge density, but current flowing from point A to point B results in a changing dipole charge density over time.

Comment: @ProfRob, Thank you but there exists what i want to check. Suppose constant current is created and long time passed (still constant current following). Then is there no change in electric field? and does it imply that curl of electric field is zero?

Comment: @ProfRob, And i'm not convinced about "and in fact no E field at all". Is this case only steady current flowing in wire? As far as i know, since there is net charge(if current is not in wire), there is net charge. And, by Gauss's law, there must be electric field.

Comment: @KHJ use Gauss's law to tell me what electric field is produced by a steady current in a wire.

Comment: @Jagerber48 as my answer says, if there is a changing charge density then that will produce a non-conservative field. However, the current can't in any case be steady in a situation where charge is being taken from one point and deposited somewhere else.

Comment: @ProfRob "However, the current can't in any case be steady in a situation where charge is being taken from one point and deposited somewhere else." I disagree with this statement? Consider a constant line current pointing in the +x direction from (-1, 0, 0) to (1, 0, 0). Sure, the current has to turn on at some moment in time (is this what you're referring to?), but after that the current can be constant for all time. You'll see charge decreasing at (-1, 0, 0) and increasing at (1, 0, 0). In this case the current is steady and is depositing charge from one point to another...?

Comment: @Jagerber48  struggling to see how the current keeps flowing as the charge builds up at one end. Of course if you impose external fields on the problem you can do it. But the net electric field will then be constant otherwise $J(t) = \sigma E(t)$.

Comment: @ProfRob I'm just theoretically prescribing a theoretically possible charge and current distribution. I'm not prescribing how the charge/current distribution is actually physically implemented.